# Usando Services para vailidar + ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, services

Estou tentando criar um service que ira verificar se um usario existe

```
class UserService
  def create_user(user_username, user_email)
    if User.find(user_username)
      false
    end
    if User.find(user_email)
      false
    end
    true
  end
end
```

E chamo ele no creta do meu controler

```
def create
  if UserService.create_user(params[:username], params[:email])
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: api_user_path(@user)
    end

    render json: "exist", status: :unprocessable_entity

  end

  render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

porem esta dando erro na linha onde chamo

```
undefined method `create_user' for UserService:Class
```

aleguem pode me ajudar? Sou novo com ruby on rails e na verdade ja até fiz uma outra pergunta de como funciona os services, mas ai encontrei algumas coisas e tentei iniciar por conta propia, porem não faço ideia se o que estou fazendo esta certo.

Só para deixar claro sei que funcionaria se colocasse direto no controler, mas estou tentando aprender a usar services no ruby, por isso estou fazendo dessa maneira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom consegui fazer depois de ler vários artigos e pergunta para muita gente. Bom teve alguns erro no caminho tava bem errado o que eu estava fazendo.

Então para fazer a chamada do service, teria dois jeitos ou eu deveria estanciar um objeto ou dizer que meu metodo é do tipo estatico e foi essa a solução que abordei. Basta colocar um `self.<nome do metodo>` que pronto ele é estatico.

outro erro era na forma como estava fazendo as buscas. No final ficou assim:

Meu método crete no controler:

```
def create
    if UserService.create_user(params[:username], params[:email])
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        render json: @user, status: :created, location: api_user_path(@user)
        return
      end
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      return
    end

    render json: "exit", status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
```

Minha service:

```
class UserService
  def self.create_user(user_username, user_email)
    if User.find_by_username(user_username)
      return false
    end
    if User.find_by_email(user_email)
      return false
    end
    return true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Vc pode dar uma refatorada nesse serviço, usando 1 query em vez de 2 assim:

```
class UserService
  def self.create_user(user_username, user_email)
    return false if User.where("username =? or email = ?", user_username, email).any?
    true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

É possivel voce colocar seu codigo no github para ver ele por completo?
Você não precisa usar um service para isso bastaria colocar no seu users_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    render json: @user, status: :created, location: api_user_path(@user)
  else
    render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

ae no seu model User voce coloca:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :user_name, uniqueness: true
```

Importante lembrar que condiçoes de unicidade devem ser adicionadas no seu banco de dados tambem não somente na aplicação.
Espero ter ajudado.

#### EDIT

Segue uma sugestão de refactor após ver seu comentário.

```
class UserService
  def self.create_user?(user_username, user_email)
    !User.where('email = ? OR username = ?', user_email, user_username).exists?
  end
end
```

Comment: Então eu to tentando por no service, para aprender usar o service, no controler to ligado que funciona.